# Multiple attributes with the same name Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, code-snippets

I have a number of attributes with the same display name but unique slugs. When creating new variable products its impossible to tell the difference between the two.

Is it possible to include the slug in the 'add' attribute dropdown?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqdOV.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same need and somehow I could manage to achieve it by using PHP + jQuery:

Add the following to your theme **functions.php** file:

```php
// Show attribute label + slugs in wordpress admin product editing pages.
function show_attribute_slugs_in_product_edit_page( $hook ) {
    global $post;
    if ( $hook == 'post-new.php' || $hook == 'post.php' ) {
        if ( 'product' === $post->post_type ) {     
            wp_enqueue_script(  'show_slugs', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/js/show_slugs.js' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'show_attribute_slugs_in_product_edit_page', 10, 1 );
```

And create a file named **show_slugs.js** inside **your-theme > assets > js** folder with the following contents:

```js
(function( $ ){
    var attr_renamed = false;
    $(document).on('click', '#woocommerce-product-data > div.inside > div > ul > li.attribute_tab > a', function(){ 
        if (attr_renamed === false) {
            $("#product_attributes > div.toolbar.toolbar-top > select option").not(":nth-child(1)").each(function() {
                var attr_label = $(this).text();
                var attr_value = $(this).val().replace('pa_', '');
                $(this).text(attr_label + ' (' + attr_value + ')');
                attr_renamed = true;
            });
        }
    });
})( jQuery );
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WESgN.jpg)